# creating a function in for-loop with index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-google-maps

I am trying to create an object in a for loop , and add a click function in the loop which can call another  function and pass in the index - so that I know which object it was that was clicked.  Here is the loop:

```
        var markers = [];
        for (x = 0; x < response.data.length; x++) {
            var ret = {
                onClicked: function () { onMarkerClicked(x); },
                locationId: response.data[x].CASO_nid,
                id: x,  //-shows proper index
                latitude: response.data[x].Latitude,
                longitude: response.data[x].Longitude,
                title: x,  // shows proper index
                showWindow: false,
                fit: true
            };
            markers.push(ret);

        }
        $scope.results = markers;
```

now when I look at the objects created in the console I see that every place that I added the x got set correctly , except in that click function , there is is just `x`.  The problem is that when I click this object after it is created then they all have `x` as the last number that it was set to.    How can I write this function to properly get the ndex , and not just the final number??

```
 see in console:


 0:  
Objectfit:
trueid: 0 
idKey: 0 
latitude: 42.0230636
locationId:10299 
longitude: -87.9620276
 onClicked: function () { onMarkerClicked(x); }
 showWindow: false
 title: 0
```

Comment: For future reference, `for ( let ... )` and `for ( const ... )` have been defined in current ECMAScript 6 drafts to be alternatives to using a closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating closures for each loop:

```
for (index = 0; index < response.data.length; index++) {
     (function(x) {
            var ret = {
                onClicked: function () { onMarkerClicked(x); },
                locationId: response.data[x].CASO_nid,
                id: x,  //-shows proper index
                latitude: response.data[x].Latitude,
                longitude: response.data[x].Longitude,
                title: x,  // shows proper index
                showWindow: false,
                fit: true
            };
            markers.push(ret);
      }(index))
 }
```

Another solution using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) as this also creates closures.

```
response.data.forEach(function (value, x){
    var ret = {
                onClicked: function () { onMarkerClicked(x); },
                locationId: value.CASO_nid,
                id: x,  //-shows proper index
                latitude: value.Latitude,
                longitude: value.Longitude,
                title: x,  // shows proper index
                showWindow: false,
                fit: true
            };
        markers.push(ret);
});
```

Comment: do you have a link to something that can explain why I was getting this wrong , and how this fixed it? I am at a loss to what I was doing wrong and as to why this works

Comment: @Scott Selby: you could take a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures